# Flex circuit solid or hatch copper pour

Tags: led, copper-pour, fpc

I have a flex circuit board with 5 [LED](http://www.osram-os.com/Graphics/XPic8/00149815_0.pdf)s mounted on it.

I have large copper areas attached to the LEDs for improved heat dissipation.

I read [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/solid-ground-plane-vs-hatched-ground-plane) that "With a hatched plane, the moisture can exit the flexible carrier material, whereas it is trapped under solid planes"

This is a different question because it involves LEDs that *require* solid copper areas for heat dissipation.

Since the copper areas are only on one side of the flex, should I still hatch the copper areas?

If hatching the areas is recommended, how can I calculate the required hatched area for heat dissipation?

Comment: How many watt's / cm^2 ?

Comment: The hatch or diamond pattern is normally used for RF circuits only, or high-speed logic over 50 MHZ.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solid ground-plane vs Hatched ground-plane](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/solid-ground-plane-vs-hatched-ground-plane)

Comment: @Tony about 125mW per LED, anywhere from 80 to 150 mm^2 per LED copper.

Comment: I'd be a bit concerned about the "flex" part. If this is meant to flex a lot and often, a big homogeneous plane may crack and split.

Comment: @Trevor_G The flex is only moved during installation and then fixed but may be subject to vibration. Are hatched areas better able to withstand flexing?

Comment: @Dutch2  OEM suggests 9 mm² per corner anode pad. I suggest 625 mm²/W is minimum .  so 80 mm² is good or more  hashed outside the 9 mm² pads with free air.  Vibration or resonance and fatigue to copper must be limited in travel.  THis heatsinking could be better than some cheap stripleds.

Comment: @Dutch2 a crack in the copper will propagate through a solid pour. Hatched it has rip-stops.

Comment: @Tony I believe that is the answer, 9mm² solid copper per anode like the datasheet recommends and the remaining area hatched.

Comment: We have designed several rigid-flex circuits and have them manufactured by a good supplier. I have never heard that hatching copper helps with moisture or crack propagation. One reason to hatch copper is to increase flexibility. I have always used solid copper planes, it has not been a problem.